# Blackberry WARNING: Cannot layout field, insufficient height or width

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-5

I'm getting the following error when a screen should appear:
"WARNING: Cannot layout field, insufficient height or width".

Working with BB 5.0.

This screen es called from 3 different screen, and its shows 50% of the screen or 80%, depending on which screen is pushing it.

This one only have one banner at the top (field), some BasicEditField, one DateField, a vew ObjectChoiceField and at the end 2 buttons.

Why is this error showing up now? (2 days ago it didnt and is the same screen that worked fine before). Where should i check for errors?

Also, is there some limit of height or width that a screen can manage?

Code for the banner,

```
public static Field getBanner() {

    Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE);

        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.FIELD_VCENTER);

        final Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo_40px.png");
        BitmapField _bitmap1 = new BitmapField(logo);
        int i = Display.getWidth();
        i = i - logo.getWidth();
        i = i / 2;
        _bitmap1.setSpace(i, 5);
        hfm.add(_bitmap1);
        hfm.setBackground(bg);
    return hfm;
}
```

Regards.

update:

on the screen creation i have this:
super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL_MASK | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR)

Without this, its works fine the screen. But i wont be able to scroll down, right?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your banner code.  Something else is wrong.  Please show **all** the layout code for this screen (all code that adds fields, lays them out, sets sizes, etc.).

Comment: on the creation of the screen, i have: super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL_MASK | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR). with out this is works fine, but i wont be hable to scroll, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding both `_bitmap1` and `vfm` to `hfm`, and `vfm` has `Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH` set. It would work better, I think, to add `_bitmap1` to `vfm`.

EDIT

It may be that your logo (with the added space) is too big for the banner area on the screen. Perhaps something like this would work:

```
public static Field getBanner() {

    Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE);
    final Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo_40px.png");
    final BitmapField _bitmap1 = new BitmapField(logo);
    _bitmap1.setSpace((Display.getWidth() - logo.getWidth()) / 2, 5);

    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.FIELD_VCENTER) {
        protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
            super.sublayout(width, height);
            setExtent(width, Math.min(_bitmap1.getPreferredHeight(), height));
        }
    }
    hfm.add(_bitmap1);
    hfm.setBackground(bg);
    return hfm;
}
```

Comment: erased the vfm but still happening. I dont know if the problem is there. Just show that code cuz it was different from the simple screen.

Comment: @GuillermoVarini - I added another suggestion (with code) to my answer.

Comment: i tried with ur code, still happening. I dont know if the this banner is the problem. Does a screen have limited height or width??

Comment: @GuillermoVarini - Screens do have dimensions limited by the physical display. Try removing the banner entirely to see if the problem is elsewhere. If the problem goes away, try putting in a very simple banner (e.g., just a white background). Perhaps the banner itself is not the problem but rather it is using up space needed elsewhere.

Comment: @Tedd Hopp first, thx a lot for the comments. I removed the banner and still happening. Also some times is shows less (80% or 50% of entire screen).

Comment: @GuillermoVarini - That's weird. Are you using something other than a `MainScreen` for this? (I assumed you were using `MainScreen` because only `MainScreen` supports a banner field.)